# How to hook iaudioclient api functions?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, core-audio

There are some audio data I would like to read before it gets outputted from an application. According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) iaudioclient is a user mode interface implemented via Audioses.dll and Mmdevapi.dll. Would hooking these two dlls hook iaudioclient's functions? How would one go about hooking this interface?

Comment: Hook audioses alone will do, it is quite deep to dig into the COM interfaces.

Comment: @MinLin: Have you successsfully hooked iaudioclient interface before?

Comment: Dll wrapper yes, in process injection no.

Comment: @MinLin: Would dll wrapper be enough for my usage?

Comment: Depends on what application you want to hook, how many control you have over the application.

Comment: @MinLin: I am trying to hook Windows Media Player.

Comment: Yes, then make a fake audioses.dll and place in the same folder as the media player. Seems to me replacing the system audioses dll would work for a short time after replacing, but later fail due to unknown reason.

Comment: @MinLin: do you think the technique described by this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153096/Intercepting-Calls-to-COM-Interfaces is viable for process injection?

Comment: Yes, the vtable approach can be used for either in process injection or dll wrapper.

Comment: @MinLin: Alright thank you I will that the method described in the article.